# How to iterate over associative array getting the current and the next key on each iteration?

Tags: php, loops

I want to iterate over an array that has random strings as keys. and i have some other object from which i need to call method that takes current key and following key as an argument in single iteration.

Comment: You don't need an iterator to iterate over array. to iterate over array you need **foreach**

Comment: sorry, just edited the question

Comment: foreach ($orders as $key => value) $some_other_object->method($key);

Comment: i need to call method that takes current key and following key as an arguments in single iteration.

Comment: $keys = array_keys($orders); foreach ($keys as $i => $key)  $some_other_object->method($key, $keys[$i+1] ?? null);

Answer (score 1):

Just flip your question upside down: rather than the current and *next* key, return the *previous* key and the current key.

```php
$prev = null; 
foreach($orders as $key => $value) {
  if ($prev !== null) {
    $some_other_object->method($prev, $key); 
  }
  $prev = $key;
}
$some_other_object->method($prev, null); // last item, no "next" key.
```

Comment: Iteresting solution, thanks!